# Sql code into kdb code

Tags: sql-server, kdb

I am taking a query in SQL Server and trying to write it in KDB. I have done this before without issue but this time the kdb query seems to be returning a different amount of rows than SQL when it should return the same. My SQL code is:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM tbl_Master
INNER JOIN map_2012
ON tbl_Master.RM_ID = map_2012.RMID
LEFT JOIN src_CQ
ON map_2012.INST = src_CQ.INST
```

My kdb code is

```
Y:map_2012 ij `RMID xkey select RMID:RM_ID, RG_ID, RM_Name from 
tbl__Master
Y:src_CQ lj `INST xkey Y
```

It is simple code but I can not figure out why the returned rows are so much different

Comment: what are the row counts?

Comment: The SQL code returns a over 300,000, the kdb code right around 600,000. And I have checked it it were just duplicates and it does not seem to be

Comment: Y:map_2012 ej `RMID xkey select RMID:RM_ID, RG_ID, RM_Name from 
tbl__Master`;
`Y:Y lj `INST xkey src_CQ should work. also suggest bring some example to test sql vs kdb code. NB: eq behaves differently with different kdb+ version

Answer (score 1):

In SQL query you left join `src_CQ` to `map_2012`. To do the same in KDB `map_2012` has to be on the left and `src_CQ` on the right:

```
Y:Y lj `INST xkey src_CQ
```

Also note, that in case `map_2012` has duplicate values in `RMID` column or `src_CQ` has duplicate values in `INST` column, keying of  table in KDB will remove rows with the duplicates. Under these circumstances another approach is required, I believe equi-join `eq` will help in this case.

Comment: That did not solve my issue. It did reduce my row count from 600,000 to around 5,000 but it should be returning at around 300,000.